# How to prove that equation?

Tags: number-theory

Guys i can't solve this from few days .. it's from Internet:

> $ pq + 1 = x^2$

like

> $3 \times 5 + 1 = 4 \times 4$

Where **p** and **q** are simple numbers and they are twins.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you mean $p,q$ are "twin primes"? And do you mean $x^2$ on the right side?

Comment: What is the question?  $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$ so you can just take $p=x-1,q=x+1$.  I don't know what "simple" or "twins" might mean.

Comment: @coffeemath, yeah, edited!

Comment: You still didn't say they are twin *primes* [of course as mlf's comment shows one doesn't need dhem to be prime, just differ by $2.$]

Comment: Nope, and Q and P must be primes.

Comment: How to prove that equation?

Comment: If $p,q$ are twin primes, then $p+1=q-1=x$, say. Then identically,
$$pq = (x-1)(x+1) = x^2-1$$
so
$$pq+1 = x^2$$
This idea has altready been given to you by more than one comment. Also, as you can see, primeness of $p,q$ is irrelevant. The only thing you need in order to prove the identity is that $p,q$ are two apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim: There always exists an integer given any twin primes $p,q$**

We can write $pq=p(p+2)$ assuming that $q$ is the larger among the two.

And $x^2-1$ simplifies into $(x-1)(x+1)$ the two having a difference of $2$.

Therefore, the equation always holds, with $x=p+1$ and this proves our claim.